# Find all semidirect products of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $C_2 $

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, semidirect-product

> **Problem:** Find all semidirect products of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $C_2$ (the cyclic group of order $2$).

**My attempt:** We know that $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ is a cyclic group of order $4$. To find all semidirect products of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $\text{C}_2 = \langle {a\rangle}$ we have to find a homomorphism $\theta \colon \text{C}_2 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$. We have $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+) \cong \{\sigma_k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}, (k,4)=1\} = \{\sigma_1,\sigma_3\}$, $\text{C}_2 = \{a^0,a^1\} = \{1,a\}$. So we define $\theta$ as follow $\theta\colon \text{C}_2 \rightarrow \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$, $\langle a \rangle \mapsto \sigma_1,\sigma_3$. Group $G = \{(1,\sigma_1),(1,\sigma_3),(a,\sigma_1),(a,\sigma_3)\}$ is a semidirect product of $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ by $\text{C}_2$.

Please check my solution. Is that true? Thank all!

Comment: The order of $G$ should be $8$, not $4$.

Comment: It is either $C_4\times C_2$ or $D_8$.

Comment: But $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ has four elements.

Comment: $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_4)\cong C_2$.

Comment: @HongyiHuang What do you mean? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find $G = \langle a\rangle:\langle b\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_4:\mathbb{Z}_2$, a semi-direct product.

You correctly find that there is a homomorphism $\langle b\rangle\to\mathrm{Aut}(\langle a\rangle)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$, so $b^{-1}ab = a^m$ for $m = 1$ or $m = 3$.

If $m = 1$, then $a$ and $b$ are commutative. In this case $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$.

If $m = 3$, then $bab = a^{-1}$. This is isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_8$.

Comment: A little question: when $m=3$, why $bab=a^{-1}$?

Comment: $a^3 = a^{-1}$ and $b = b^{-1}$ by definitions.

Comment: From $b^{-1}ab = a^3 \Rightarrow b^2 b^{-1} ab = b^2 a^3 \Rightarrow bab = b^2 a^3 = a^3$, it implies $bab=a^{-1}$ by $a^3 = a^{-1}$, but $\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$ has order $4$.

Comment: Yes, $\langle a\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_4$ implies $a^4 = 1$, and so $a^3 = a^{-1}$.@Minh

Comment: Oh! I understand this.